# (Python) "matplotlib" does not work in my Pycharm

Tags: python

"matplotlib" does not work in my Pycharm.
My sample code is at below.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    x=[1,2,3]
    y=[10,20,30]

    plt.plot(x,y)

    plt.show()
```

At terminal, it works successfully. However at Pycharm, it does not work without any error message.

When I run the code, it says

```
"/usr/local/bin/python3.8/Users/colde/PycharmProjects/practice/test.py" and stops like it is taken in infinite loop.
```

Could you help this problem?
Best regards, Colde.

Comment: Can you get anything at all to work in pycharm?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000143610-Problems-with-Interactive-Plotting-in-Debug-Mode-in-PyCharm-Version-2017-1 try this maybe it helps.

Comment: @COLDE Are you able to import matplotlib package?